# YouTube: is there a way to get email notification ONLY when I upload a new video?

Tags: youtube

I'd like to get the notification when the upload is done. But I don't want any other emails from YouTube.

Comment: Welcome. Please check  [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking). As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official YouTube [Help site](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7123737?hl=en)

> Turn off emails from YouTube
>
> To turn off an email notification, click the unsubscribe link at the
>   bottom of the email. You can also choose to unsubscribe from certain
>   types of email or all emails from YouTube. Unsubscribe from certain
>   types of emails
>
> To unsubscribe from certain types of emails from YouTube, go to your
>   account notification settings:
>
> - Sign in to YouTube.
> - In the top right, click your profile picture  and then Settings .
> - In the left menu, click Notifications.
> - Under "I’d like to receive email updates from YouTube about," uncheck the boxes for the types of email updates you'd like to stop
>     getting.

[image]

Comment: sorry. but the answer is almost off-topic

Comment: Interesting. ;)